# React: Cannot assign to read only property '_status' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, code-splitting

I've been struggling over this error for a while now. It happens when I try to open react-bootstrap Modal with dynamically passed lazy component referrence and props to render it inside. It worked with classic import.

[image]

First row points to some react's internal lazy handler:

[image]

This is how modals are handled inside my ModalProvider:

```js
const ModalList = React.memo(({ modalList, closeModalByIndex, confirmModalExitByIndex }) =>
    modalList.map((modalDef, index) => {
        const closeModal = () => closeModalByIndex(index);
        const onConfirmExitChange = (confirmExit) => confirmModalExitByIndex(index, confirmExit);
        const props = { ...modalDef, key: index, closeModal, onConfirmExitChange };
        switch (modalDef.type) {
            case TYPE_LIST:
                return (
                    <React.Suspense fallback={fallback}>
                        <ListModal {...props} />
                    </React.Suspense>
                );
            case TYPE_FORM:
                return (
                    <React.Suspense fallback={fallback}>
                        <FormModal {...props} />
                    </React.Suspense>
                );
            case TYPE_LIST_MULTI:
                return (
                    <React.Suspense fallback={fallback}>
                        <ListMultiModal {...props} />
                    </React.Suspense>
                );
            default:
                return null;
        }
    })
);
```

And this is how it is passed:

```js
const openListModal = (Component, componentProps) => openModal(Component, componentProps, TYPE_LIST);
```

Anyone with deeper understanding what could possibly cause this?

Answer (score 4):

Found out by trial by error. It was caused by immer's produce function which builds read-only deep copy of object.

```
    setModalList(
        produce(modalList, (modalList) => {
            modalList.push({ Component, componentProps, type, show: true });
        })
    );
```